# comparing images matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, mathematical-morphology

Ok so let's say i have a binary image containing the pixel representation for 1,2,A,B or whatever. But for now let's just consider 1

```
0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0
0 1 1 0
0 1 1 0
0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0
```

and then i have another image containing the standard representation of 1.

Now what i wan't is to compare these two images and decide whether my first image contains pixel values for 1 or not.

What kind of algorithms are available at my disposal ?

Please i do not require the name of the matlab function for image comparison as has been the answer for similar questions. Rather than that i require the name of some algorithms that can be used to solve this problem so that i can implement it on my own in C#

Comment: This should be asked in the dsp SE...

Answer (score 0):

What you need to compute is the `distance` between your image and the ground truth. This distance can be stated in many different ways. Search google for `similarity measures on binary data`. See here a [review](http://www.iiisci.org/journal/CV%24/sci/pdfs/GS315JG.pdf).